# Chrome Dev Tools - Display Special Characters In Console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, html-entities, console.log

In Chrome Dev Tools, is there a way to display special characters in the console (when using `console.log()` from a JavaScript file, as opposed to typing it in directly in the console)? For example, if I try `console.log("&clubs;")`, it just outputs the string literal, but not the actual clubs character (♣).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show the ♣ symbol on your console, then `console.log("♣")` or `console.log("\u2663")` (unicode version) should work just fine.

---

If you need a method that converts HTML entity codes to the actual characters in the console, then you can use this:

```
function entityToChar(entity) {
  var s = document.createElement('span');
  s.innerHTML = entity;
  return s.innerHTML;
}
```

For JavaScript `&clubs;` is just a string, you need to tell the browser that it is HTML.

[image: converting HTML entity code to character in DevTools console]

Comment: Strangely enough - when I type `console.log('♣')` directly in the console, it outputs it just fine; but when I use `console.log('♣')` ***in a JavaScript file***, then it outputs `â™£` - ***that's*** the problem I'm having.

Comment: @jbyrd ah, now I see what you are trying to achieve. OK, so the most reliable solution is to use unicode character notation like so: `console.log("\u2663")`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @jbyrd: Two years later... chances are you're using a different editor, but the reason that was happening was that the document was being saved as ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8. You need to add a UTF-8 charset attribute to the `head`, or use a text editor that adds a UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM) to your file. Not sure what the solution for Node is, but that's how to solve it for browsers.

Answer (score -1):

If you type `document.documentElement.outerHTML.includes("enter what you are looking for between these quotes")` the console will give you back "true" or "false", with a bit of context and the line number in the HTML file on the right, which you can click on to see its position in the document as a whole.

Alternately, in JavaScript, you can use document.documentElement.outerHTML to get a string containing the whole HTML file you are using, than use indexOf("&club;") or contains("&club;") to get the position/existence of whatever you're looking for, and console.log() the results. Example:

```
console.log(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("&club;")!=-1?
            "&club; is present! WOW! at character "+document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("&club;"):
            "&club; has not appeared.");
```

I do not believe there is any way to make this happen automatically.